# What am I doing wrong moving this Azure Pipelines variable between stages?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So in stage 1, named `build`, in a job called `build_app` I have a PowerShell task named `SetEnvVariables` that does this:

```
$applicationConfig = Get-Content -Raw config/application-config.json | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=INSTALLER_VERSION;isOutput=true]$($applicationConfig.version)"
```

I'm having great difficulty using this variable in a later stage, here's what I'm trying based on some of the examples I've seen:

```
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: Create_Release
    displayName: 'Publish New Version'
    environment: 
      name: 'release-production'
    variables:
      appVersion: $[stageDependencies.build.outputs['build_app.SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION']]
```

I've also tried just

```
  variables:
    appVersion: stageDependencies.build.outputs['build_app.SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION']
```

without success.

I've also tried:

```
  variables:
    appVersion: $[ stageDependencies.build.build_app.outputs['SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION'] ]
```

(with the job in the chain of dot-accessed object/properties) as the documentation conflicts with some of the answers on StackOverflow on this point - this doesn't work in the exact same way.

In both cases, failure looks like a totally empty string.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, & it feels like there *must* be a less awkward way to handle sharing of variables between stages but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: I've just re-retrieved the value of the variable in one of the deploy script steps instead of trying to use a stage variable; I don't understand Microsoft's documentation at all on this and none of the other StackOverflow answers seem to fix my problem, but I'm interested if there's an answer as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you add the stage definition with the job and task to the question, please?

Comment: For the `build_app` job, is it a `job` or a `deployment` job? The syntax is different.

Comment: It's a regular `job`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I managed to generate the output variable from the `build_job` and output the value in the `deployment` job of the downstream `deploy` stage. Kindly note that `deployment` jobs use a different syntax from traditional `job` for output variables.

- If the `build_job` is a traditional `job`, in which the output variable `INSTALLER_VERSION` is generated, we can use `appVersion: $[stageDependencies.build.build_app.outputs['SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION']]`. Please also add `dependOn: build` property for the `deploy` stage. By default, each stage in a pipeline depends on the one just before it in the YAML file. If you need to refer to a stage that isn't immediately prior to the current one, you can override this automatic default by adding a `dependsOn` section to the stage.

  ```
  stages:
  - stage: build
    jobs:
    - job: build_app
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: SetEnvVariables
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $applicationConfig = Get-Content -Raw config/application-config.json | ConvertFrom-Json
            Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=INSTALLER_VERSION;isOutput=true]$($applicationConfig.version)"

  - stage: deploy
    dependsOn: build
    jobs:
    - deployment: Create_Release
      displayName: 'Publish New Version'
      environment: 
        name: 'release-production'
      variables:
        appVersion: $[stageDependencies.build.build_app.outputs['SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION']]
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:
           steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              name: SetEnvVariables
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: | 
                  Write-Output $(appVersion)
  ```

  [image]
- If the `build_job` is a `deployment` job, in which the output variable `INSTALLER_VERSION` is generated, we should use `appVersion: $[stageDependencies.build.build_app.outputs['build_app.SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION']]` instead.

  ```
  stages:
  - stage: build
    jobs:
    - deployment: build_app
      environment: 
        name: 'release-production'
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self
          - task: PowerShell@2
            name: SetEnvVariables
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $applicationConfig = Get-Content -Raw config/application-config.json | ConvertFrom-Json
                Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=INSTALLER_VERSION;isOutput=true]$($applicationConfig.version)"
  - stage: deploy
    dependsOn: build
    jobs:
    - deployment: Create_Release
      displayName: 'Publish New Version'
      environment: 
        name: 'release-production'
      variables:
        appVersion: $[stageDependencies.build.build_app.outputs['build_app.SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION']]
      strategy:
       runOnce:
         deploy:
           steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              name: SetEnvVariables
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: | 
                  Write-Output $(appVersion)
  ```

Here are some documents we can refer to and figure out the syntax. Hope the information could help.

[Deployment jobs - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables)

[Set variables in scripts - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-stages)

[Expressions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependency-syntax-overview)

Comment: Thanks! I've tried $[ stageDependencies.build.build_app.outputs['SetEnvVariables.INSTALLER_VERSION'] ] , so this is the same as my setup. I'm going to mark this as answered despite the fact it doesn't work for me because it's clearly how it's supposed to work and it's helped me to make the decision not to use this system.